# Which is more fluent - longer or shorter syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-interface

I am trying to create my first fluent interface and I was just wondering what other poeple thought was more fluent and which one they would prefer to use?

```
Check.Field().Named("est").WithValueOf("sdsd").IsNotNull()

Check.Field("est").WithValueOf("sdsd").IsNotNull()

Check.Field("est").WithValue("sdsd").IsNotNull()
```

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last one definitely:

```
Check.Field("est").WithValue("sdsd").IsNotNull()
```

Answer (score 3):

I concur:

```
Check.Field("est").WithValue("sdsd").IsNotNull()
```

As short as possible, while still making sense.

Avoid noise words like `.as. .of. .and. .in.` unless they add contextual meaning.  I've seen fluent interfaces that do this, and it adds nothing useful except more typing and more hoops for the application to jump through when it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Or, to mimic some of the collections, use of [Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item.aspx):

```
Check["est"].WithValue("sdsd").IsNotNull()
```

Some might also say you should just use .IsNull() and negate the whole expression, like this, but that's a "six -vs- half a dozen" thing:

```
!Check["est"].WithValue("sdsd").IsNull()
```

Comment: I prefer IsNotNull method because you can literally read what the code is doing.

Comment: You can't even be sure IsNotNull() returns a boolean. That is even less likely in a fluent interface, where you'd return `this` - it's possible IsNotNull() returns a collection that can be further filtered (jQuery style), ...IsNotNull().IsVisible()... .  
Also, in vb this is even less readable - `not Check.filters...IsNull()`

Comment: Hence my careful wording of "some might say" :). (1) The method name starts with "Is" which is a convention for returning a Boolean, even in a fluent interface - not everything can return "this". (2) The original question was tagged as C# not VB, so I ignored "Not" and just mentioned "!".

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be:

```
Check.Field("est").IsNotNull("sdsd")
```

Something like LINQ's FirstOrDefault called with a predicate instead of filtering and then calling FirstOrDefault.

Comment: I thought of this but i didn't think it was as clear if someone know nothing about the code and literally saw "Check.Field("est").IsNotNull("sdsd")" vs "Check.Field("est").WithValue("sdsd").IsNotNull()" I would have thought the latter would be more clear.

Comment: Well the thing that confuses me, without knowing the code, is how a field with a value of "sdsd" could possibly be null (which I read to mean "have a null value").

Answer (score 0):

What is `Check`?  I suspect it's not needed at all.  I understand what you're trying to do, but remember that the expression you're trying to build will still likely end up in an if statement.  With that in mind, think about how "if check X" reads.  Not too well, imho.  Additionally, what does the 'Field' function have to do to resolve that name?  Do you have that somewhere else that you could present in a nicer way (perhaps an extension method on some base type?)

Comment: Actually I have the following cases: Check and Validate. Check will throw an exception where as validate will return a bool at the end. So I was thinking the way it would read would be as follows: public void Test(object value) { Check.Argument("value").WithValue(value).IsNotNull(); .... } and my validate case would be like: public void Test(object value) { if (Validate.That("value").WithValue(value).IsNotNull()) { ... }  }

Comment: Also as far as what field means. There are actually 2 possibilities here Check.Field & Check.Argument. The difference being that Check.Argument will throw exceptions like ArgumentNullException where as Check.Field will throw a NullReferenceException.